# tedious.js set requestTimeout = 0 but still got timed out

Tags: node.js, tedious

I have this config file:

```
{
  "userName": "user",
  "password": "pass",
  "server": "shrd-cw",

  "options": {
    "encrypt": true,
    "requestTimeout": 0
  }
}
```

However, I still received requestTimeout error:

```
{ [RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms]
  name: 'RequestError',
  message: 'Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms',
  code: 'ETIMEOUT' }
```

Comment: I was able to make connection with results so I'm pretty sure the username and password were parsed correctly. Only when I try to pull down too much data that timeout happens

Comment: Honestly not sure why it's behaving that way - you might want to open an issue in the Google group or GitHub issues. You could also try setting it to something really big like `200000` and see if that works? (Even though the docs say it supports `0`).

Comment: Yes that's very strange. When I set it to 30000 or 400000, it was respected. However, when I put 0, I still got request timed out

Comment: Definitely post a bug then - hopefully they'll look at it.